# Tensorflow in bazel pip requirement doesn't install all dependencies

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I have a very simple test where I am trying to install tensorflow as a pip requirement using bazel but the binary fails because not all of the dependencies of tensorflow are installed with it. The `BUILD.bazel` looks like this:

```
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", _py_binary = "py_binary")
load("@pip//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

_py_binary(
    name = "tensorflow_test",
    srcs = glob(["*.py"]),
    main = "main.py",
    deps = [
        requirement("tensorflow"),
    ],
)
```

and in my workspace I have:

```
load("@python//:defs.bzl", py_interpreter = "interpreter")
load("//rules/python:pip.bzl", "pip_requirements")

pip_requirements(
    name = "pip",
    interpreter = py_interpreter,
    requirements_file = "//py:requirements.txt.lock",
)
```

The target `//py:requirements.txt.lock` is a requirements file that not only has tensorflow included, but all of its dependencies as well, tagged as "via tensorflow"

In the same directory of the `BUILD.bazel` file is a python file called `main.py` that is just doing the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.random.normal(shape=(1, 2)))
```

I can built this target fine, but when I try to run it, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'absl'` which I believe is a dependency of tensorflow. I have hard coded that dependency in and tried again but now we get the same error for some other dependency that didn't make it into the binary.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: That could be issue with python version installed. Python 2.x, Python 3.x Make sure you have both Pythons version on your machine have the  below package installed properly
 
'pip install absl-py'
'pip3 install absl-py'

Comment: I don't think its a python version issue. I would have thought that I don't need to have explicitly installed all 20+ dependencies of tensorflow in my build but rather they would be installed like normal when doing a simple `pip install tensorflow`